# GAM - parametric coefficients - what is mgcViz::pterm() actually plotting?

Tags: data-visualization, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, ggplot2, parametric

I built a GAM with two categorical variables and two smooth terms, following this structure:

```
model <- ik ~ population_id_cat + s_status + s(n_locs, bs = "re") + s(animal_id, bs = "re")
```

The model summary for the parametric coefficients is:

```
Parametric coefficients:
                                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                      1.90509    0.07798  24.432  < 2e-16 ***
population_id_catB              -1.08790    0.13199  -8.242 2.27e-16 ***
population_id_catC               0.06718    0.08880   0.757 0.449368    
population_id_catD              -0.27599    0.07689  -3.589 0.000336 ***
population_id_catE              -0.33914    0.13555  -2.502 0.012391 *  
population_id_catF              -0.71104    0.07586  -9.373  < 2e-16 ***
population_id_catG              -0.39243    0.07276  -5.393 7.32e-08 ***
population_id_catH               0.31115    0.18431   1.688 0.091449 .  
population_id_catI               0.06530    0.10203   0.640 0.522174    
s_status_2a_m                   -0.16331    0.05263  -3.103 0.001930 ** 
s_status_2fam                   -0.36656    0.05200  -7.050 2.10e-12 ***
```

When I plot these coefficients with the `mgcViz::pterm()` function, the values do not seem to match the std. error (but their significance does match with the p-value provided).

For example, the plot for the parametric coefficients mentioned above:

```
gviz_model <- getViz(model)
gviz_model_1 <- pterm(gviz_model, 1)
plot(gviz_model_1) + l_ciBar(colour = "blue") + l_fitPoints(colour = "red") + l_rug(alpha = 0.3)
```

[image]

***Question 1:***

What values are actually plotted in this plot? They seem to match the "Estimate" value from the summary, but they do not match the "Std. Error" (e.g., look at population H, according to the std error, the o value would be significant and therefore would be above 0).

If I plot the `Estimate+-Std. Error` in a `ggplot` (which is my goal, because I want to plot these parametric values for two models in the same plot), I get this instead:

```
gviz_model_pop <- termplot(gviz_model, se = TRUE, plot = FALSE)$population_id_cat
ggplot(gviz_model_pop , aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
     geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-se, ymax=y+se), width=.15, size=1, position=position_dodge(0.2))  +
     geom_point(position=position_dodge(0.2), size=3.5, shape=16)
```

[image]

Similar trends, but the interval is definitely not the same (and influences the significance of each category).

***Question 2:***

If I want to plot these parametric coefficients for two models in the same plot, and I would need to use the output from pterm(), instead of extracting the estimates/std error as I did previously, how can I do this? Preferably with a ggplot output.

***Question 3:***

If I want to plot these parametric coefficients including the intercept (to make the plot more interpretable), as mentioned [here in "Transformed standard errors (2)"](https://noamross.github.io/gams-in-r-course/chapter2), how do I do it? Do I need separate calculations or is there a function for the parametric coefficients too? Preferably with a ggplot output.

Thank you very much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Q1

The blue bars are *confidence* intervals formed (likely) as +/- 2 * `Std. err`

#### Q2

I think this would be easier with `parametric_effects()` from my {gratia} package; what `pterm()` seems to be doing is wrapping up the model object with some extra information, which doesn't seem to be the information computed for the plot.

Using the example from `?pterm`, we have

```r
library("gratia")

set.seed(3)
dat <- gamSim(1,n=1500,dist="normal",scale=20)
dat$fac <- as.factor( sample(c("A1", "A2", "A3"), nrow(dat), replace = TRUE) )
dat$logi <- as.logical( sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(dat), replace = TRUE) )
bs <- "cr"; k <- 12
b <- gam(y ~ x0 + x1 + I(x1^2) + s(x2,bs=bs,k=k) + fac + x3:fac + I(x1*x2) + logi,
         data=dat)

p <- parametric_effects(b)
```

Which gives

```
> p <- parametric_effects(b)                                                  
Interaction terms are not currently supported.
> p                                                                           
# A tibble: 6,005 × 6
   term  type       value level partial    se
   <chr> <chr>   <I<dbl>> <fct>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 x0    numeric    0.168 NA     -0.310 0.309
 2 x0    numeric    0.808 NA     -1.49  1.48 
 3 x0    numeric    0.385 NA     -0.711 0.708
 4 x0    numeric    0.328 NA     -0.605 0.602
 5 x0    numeric    0.602 NA     -1.11  1.11 
 6 x0    numeric    0.604 NA     -1.12  1.11 
 7 x0    numeric    0.125 NA     -0.230 0.229
 8 x0    numeric    0.295 NA     -0.544 0.541
 9 x0    numeric    0.578 NA     -1.07  1.06 
10 x0    numeric    0.631 NA     -1.17  1.16 
# ℹ 5,995 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

The confidence is easy to add:

```r
p <- p |>
  dplyr::mutate(lower_ci = partial - (1.96 * se), upper_ci = partial + (1.96 * se))
```

I would also append a model column to indicate which model this is:

```r
p <- p |>
  dplyr::mutate(model = rep("Model 1", nrow(p))
```

If you repeat that for the other model, to create `p2` say, you should be able to bind the two objects together with

```
p_both <- dplyr::bind_rows(p, p2)
```

You can also select which terms you want to extract the info for using the `terms` argument to `parametric_effects()`.

#### Q3

The best way to do this is to just predict from the model including *only* the constant term and parametric term of you choice. In the example from `?pterm` that I used above, there is a factor variable `fac` which we'll use to illustrate the point.

```r
# get a data slice where only `fac` varies
# hold all other variables are representative values
ds <- data_slice(b, fac = evenly(fac)) |>
  dplyr::mutate(logi = as.logical(logi)) # <-- work around bug

# use fitted_values() to predict from the model using only the effects
# of `fac` and the constant term
fv <- fitted_values(b, data = ds, terms = c("(Intercept)", "fac"))
fv
```

There's a bug in `data_slice()` currently; `data_slice()` seems to be converting logical variables to numeric. We work around that by coaxing them back to logical. And we only need this to keep `predict.gam()` happy; none of the other variables but `fac` will be used in the predictions we computed in `fv`.

Having done the above `fv` is:

```
> fv                                                                          
# A tibble: 3 × 10
  fac      x0    x1    x2 logi     x3 fitted    se  lower upper
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
1 A1    0.511 0.521 0.493 FALSE 0.476   5.75  2.55  0.753 10.8 
2 A2    0.511 0.521 0.493 FALSE 0.476   4.60  2.54 -0.367  9.57
3 A3    0.511 0.521 0.493 FALSE 0.476   2.94  2.63 -2.21   8.09
```

Here, as `fac` only had three levels, we get the three values needed for the plot. The `fitted` column is now has the intercept added to each of the parametric effects, hence `A1`, being the reference level has the same value as the intercept:

```
> coef(b)[1]                                                                  
(Intercept) 
   5.753834
```

while the other values in `fitted` are `(Intercept)` *plus* the respective coefficient for the other levels. The `lower` and `upper` columns contain the confidence interval as it would be plotted in the output from mgcViz. Note that `fitted_values()` returns, by default, predicted values on the response scale. If you have a non-Gaussian family, you can choose to keep the values on the link scale using `scale = "link"` in the call to `fitted_values()`

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful. Just a couple more details, regarding question 3, "fv" then is now interpretable directly at the scale of the response variable, right? Including the reference category. And this interpretation is independent of the other categorical variable (in your example,  "logi")?

Comment: Yes, `fv` contains fitted values from the model on the response scale (given the code shown). The interpretation isn't that these estimated effects are *independent* of the other terms. Technically they are for the reference level of `logi` (FALSE) because that is what the constant term represents `A1` *and* `FALSE`. You would get slightly different answers if you did this for `logi == TRUE`, but importantly (apart from differences in the Std err of the estimated effects) each of the estimates for `A1` is being shifted by the same value (intercept) so relative to one another the effects 1/2

Comment: ...are comparable. The isn't much you can do to avoid this; you either set `logi == FALSE` (which is implied when you use only the intercept) or you set `logi = TRUE` and you include the effect of `logi` in the `terms` argument. There are other things you could do, such as generate estimates given both values of `logi` and average those estimates; you difference those estimates, etc. Doing all that is not something that is easy to do with {gratia} (there are no canned functions to do those steps) but the {emmeans} or {marginaleffects} packages can do this and would be my goto for this 2/2

Comment: Also, the estimates will never be independent of the `logi` effect (or any other estimated effect); the coefficients associated with `fac` (in the example) are those effects *given that `logi` and the other terms are included in the model*. If you dropped `logi` from the model, the estimated effects of `fac` would change.

Comment: this is a great explanation, thank you! Actually, in my case, it would not be a bad idea to show the two effects of "logi" (In my example, social_status_2, which has 3 categories), as this would be another variable to show in a plot similar to the one for the populations. Two more (hopefully last) questions: 1) should I worry about the random effects, or somehow consider them in the "ds"/"fv" objects? 2) in the code you provided, where should I change the "logi" param? I changed it manually before creating the "fv" object but the values for "fitted" etc stayed the same

Comment: With random effects, it depends on what you are trying to do/show. Typically, when you are showing the effects of the, or selected, "fixed" terms (the scare quotes because smooths are random effects too but you wouldn't treat them as being a random drawn), you would exclude the random effects or average over them. The former is easy (just add the random effect to the `exclude` argument, or as I did here just don't include that term in the `terms` argument), the latter not so much when a non-identity link function is being used.

Comment: Regardless, the code shown would provide a value for the random effect(s) when creating `ds` and then ignore the contribution from the random effect term when creating `fv`. I'm not sure what you mean by "change the `logi` parameter", do you mean specify that you want both value `TRUE` and `FALSE` in the data slice/predicted values? If that, you should be able to do `data_slice(b, fac = evenly(fac), logi = c(FALSE, TRUE))` and you can skip the `mutate()` step as the bug doesn't affect that particular call. Now `ds` and hence `fv` will have 6 rows for the combinations of `fac` and `logi`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, it makes sense! And the code works as well, thanks a lot for your help!